# Can a thermal radiating surface be replaced by an equivalent antenna with proper current distribution?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, thermal-radiation, antennas

Thermal radiation is EM waves generated by electrons movements due to a non-zero absolute temperature. Given a certain material with such an emission at temperature T, is it possible to see it as an antenna with proper (randomic) spatial distribution of surface current J?

If true, it would be possible to get the radiated electric field (hence the radiated power per solid angle) by integrating such a randomic current distribution over the emitting surface.

My question arises because of the Lambert Cosine Law for planar bodies.

[image]

It has the same form as the [effective area of an aperture antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperture_(antenna)) (physical area projected along the observation direction). The Lambert law has been always shown to me as an experimental law. Instead, the $cos(\theta)$ dependence on the radiated power of aperture antennas is well proved through [EM problem solution](http://ece.uprm.edu/%7Epol/pdf/aperture.pdf).

Is it an hazard to extend such a proof to thermal radiation of lambertian bodies?